# PHP SELECT all from database and compare with day calendar

Tags: php, mysql, select, for-loop, pdo

I crate a calendar for the current month but I also need to check if exist a row in database with the same month and year. And than if has display a the work hours row for that day. here is my code

```
echo '
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Hours</th>
                        <th>Minutes</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody class="listUser">';

            //get how many day on the month
            $daysOfMonth = date('t', strtotime("$month/1/$year"));
            //select all from the db
            $result = $this->_dbconn->prepare('SELECT time.day, time.hours, time.minutes FROM work_time AS time WHERE year=? AND month=?');
            $result->execute(array($year, $month));
            $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            //printVar($rows);

            for($i=1; $i<$daysOfMonth; $i++){
                $i = (strlen($i) < 2)? $i = '0'.$i : $i=$i;
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>'.$year.''. $month .''.$i.'</td>';
                    echo '<td><input class="span1" type="number" /></td>';
                    echo '<td><input class="span1" type="number" /></td>';
                    echo '<td><input class="btn" type="submit" value="save" /></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            echo '
                </tbody>
            </table>';
```

Comment: Did you have a question somewhere in there?

Comment: keeping day, hours, month, year in seperate columns is really bad thing